# Range of status codes for status_code

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible 2.9.6

The playbook works well when I specify the [status codes as a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html#parameter-status_code).

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Create a new bitbucket repository
      uri:
        user: "{{username}}"
        password: "{{password}}"
        method: POST
        body_format: json
        body: "{{ lookup('file','create-repo.json')}}"
        return_content: yes
        status_code: [200,201,400,401,403,409,500]
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        url: "{{url}}"
      register: bitbucketResponse

    - name: show bitbucket reponse
      debug:
        msg: "{{bitbucketResponse}}"
...
```

I wish to specify a range( 200 to 500) but I couldn't figure out if it is supported e.g: status_code: [200:500]

Comment: you might have to write a python {% %}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use [range](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#range). For example

```
    status_code: "{{ range(200, 500, 1)|list }}"
```

Comment: Just to be cautious, as per the documentation, 'Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.'. I assume it will create a list of 300 or so integers which might be overkill when compared listing the response codes.

Comment: What result of "*`range( 200 to 500)`*" do you expect?

Comment: All I am saying is that range will return a List containing 200-500 i.e 400 elements(200,201,202....499), hence, the developer should decide whether he wants to have this list created by range or simply specify the way I have did. Both the approaches work fine, unless I am missing something.